# How to reply to from popup Pidgin notification message itself in unity?

Tags: notification, pidgin, notify-osd, indicator-message

I want to reply to IM notification of pidgin popup in unity desktop, rather than opening a new window of concern IM. It would be much better to rply from popup notification message itself of piding. Anyone with solution please

I want the functionality as that is in gnome shell. where popup message apper-> you write the message within buuble to sent. Just two activity away

Currently in unity desktop
popup message appears-> we click on blue notification icon in menu bar -> click the appropriate message -> new window appear -> write the message to sent. so long activities. I want it in simple two steps

Comment: Short answer is you don't. However you can reply messages in the notification on Gnome Shell, at least with Empathy messenger.

Comment: @amit-rane you need to install the package `pidgin-libnotify`. Then it will appear in messaging menu. When any one sends a message it will turn blue. You click on it & voila

Comment: @KhurshidAlam I want to rply instantly from the popup bubble that appear as notification. Rather than going on menu bar-> click on blue notification icon->open up the window->write the message to send. Long activity. How about popup appear->write messge to send

Comment: @xangua Yeah i want the same functionality to be in UNITY dash as that used in gnome shell

Answer (score 0):

Unity's notification are unobtrusive & can not be interacted with. Unity provide messaging menu (indicator-messages) for that purpose.

First you need to install the package `pidgin-libnotify`.

Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pidgin-libnotify
```

Now open pidgin add a account & enable `libnotify` plugin from `Pidgin->Tools->plugins`

Then it will appear under messaging menu (as shown in the image) & keep running in background even if you close the main window.

[image]

When your contacts sends a message, the indicator will turn blue & you will see your contact under pidgin sub-menu (as shown in the picture). C**lick on that & it will open the contact with latest message.**

[image]

DONE!

Comment: I Know the above one but 
I want to rply instantly from the popup bubble that appear as notification as that in gnome shell. Rather than going on menu bar-> click on blue notification icon->open up the window->write the message to send. Long activity. How about popup appear->write messge to send

Comment: That's not possible. Ubuntu does not store notifications.Beside I think you are complicating things too much. Even in `gnome-shell` it only works if there is a single popup. For multiple messages, it goes to `notification area`. For example,What happens when you get 30 consecutive popups? Which popup do you want to open? For me, Ubuntu's method is much more unobtrusive & its its just two-click away.